# TypeError: AuthMiddlewareStack() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inner'

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

Hi I am trying to build ASGI APPLICATION but
I get this error

```
File "/home/marwan/Desktop/Gowd/gowd_project/config/routing.py", line 8, in <module>
    AuthMiddlewareStack(
TypeError: AuthMiddlewareStack() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inner'
```

and this is my routing.py file

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.security.websocket import AllowedHostsOriginValidator
from django.urls import path

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            # URLRouter([...]) # Empty for now because we don't have a consumer yet.
        )
    )
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code

```
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter([])
        )
    ),
})
```